# Google script add row with date only on certain dates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a Google Sheet that automatically adds new rows with a weekday date in the first columns, two days before the respective date (Mondays get added on Saturday, Tuesdays on Sunday, etc.). For this I have written the following function:

```
function addRowsWithDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  var Today = new Date();
  Today.setDate(Today.getDate()+0); // I am using this to experiment with different dates
  var newDate = new Date();
  var dayOfWeek = Today.getDay();
  
  if (dayOfWeek<=3 || dayOfWeek==6){ // On Saturday through Wednesday
    newDate.setDate(Today.getDate()+2);
    ss.insertRowsBefore(1, 1); // Add new rows
    ss.getRange(1, 1).setValue(newDate); // Set date to the day after tomorrow 
  }
}
```

This works as expected if I leave the `+0` as it is, or comment out that line, but once I start changing that value to experiment with what will happen when I run this code on different dates I returns dates in other months. For example, offsetting today to `+3` (as of 31 September) adds a row with 5 September. Now that I am typing this I see the issue is possibly with `getDate()` returning the day of the month instead of the week like I read [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/date-field#getDay()). Is that correct? And if so, is there another function that returns the day of the week in Google Sheets scripts?

EDIT: it seems to be some wrapping issue. When I set `+3` it returns 5 September instead of 5 October and if I set `-30` I get 3 October again.

Comment: Try using getDay() function to get the day and then procced with if() function to increment accordingly.

Comment: @Harsh I don't follow. Is that not what I am doing already?

Comment: today is Wednesday. If you add +1, then it is Thursday. The latter is the 4th day of the week. Remember Sunday is 0, therefore Thursday is 4. Your if condition will be skipped for +1 or +2.

Comment: @Marios Yes, that is how I want it to be. The idea is that I can run this script daily without adding weekend days to the spreadsheet. The problem is than when I set +3 (pretend it is Saturday), it returns 5 September instead of Monday 5 October.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a `new Date()` for `newDate`, define `newDate` as `new Date(Today)` and then add 2 days to it inside the if loop.

**Solution:**

```
function addRowsWithDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  var Today = new Date();
  Today.setDate(Today.getDate()+3); // I am using this to experiment with different dates
  var newDate = new Date(Today);
  var dayOfWeek = Today.getDay();
  
  
  if (dayOfWeek<=3 || dayOfWeek==6){ // On Saturday through Wednesday
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+2);
    ss.insertRowsBefore(1, 1); // Add new rows
    ss.getRange(1, 1).setValue(newDate); // Set date to the day after tomorrow 
    ss.getRange(1, 2).setValue(Today); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks you. When I add `ss.getRange(1, 2).setValue(Today);` to also print the pretend today's date it returns the same date as `newDate`. When editing `newDate`, are those changes also applied to `Today`?